# Weird output in C fork call

Tags: c, fork

I have the following C code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main ()
{

    int i=1;

    pid_t child_pid = fork();

    if (child_pid == 0) 
    {
        printf ("%d\n", i++);
        printf ("%d\n", i++);
        printf ("This is child process.");
        return 0;


    }
    else if (child_pid > 0) {
        printf ("%d\n", i++);
        printf ("This is parent process.");
    }

    else {
    printf("Fork failed");
    }

}
```

I compiled the following as follows: `gcc testFork.c` and ran the code by typing `./a.out`.

The output i got was:

```
vmw_ubuntu@vmwubuntu:~/Desktop/Test C$ ./a.out
1
This is parent process.vmw_ubuntu@vmwubuntu:~/Desktop/Test C$ 1
2
This is child process.
```

Why is `vmw_ubuntu@vmwubuntu:~/Desktop/Test C$` appearing in the middle of nowhere?

I am simply expecting this output:

```
vmw_ubuntu@vmwubuntu:~/Desktop/Test C$ ./a.out
1
This is parent process.1
2
This is child process.
```

Comment: As soon as the parent process finishes, the shell will resume; the first thing it dies is print the command prompt. However, the child is still waiting to start at that point.

Comment: It is your prompt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you didn't add a newline '\n' escape character at the end of your printf call; and thus, when your parent process returned to your shell, the prompt of your shell `vmw_ubuntu@vmwubuntu:~/Desktop/Test C$' was appended to the end.

Remember that when you call 'fork' you're creating 2 separate copies of the same process. It's no longer 1 program, and the parent can return before the child.

EDIT:

To achieve the output you want, you need to insert a call to the 'waitpid' function. see http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably is that printf function is buffered: [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)
Disable buffering or use write(..), which is unbuffered. And there is no problem with fork - it works as specified.